# How to flush a System.err buffer?

Tags: java, stream, output, flush

Could you Java gurus tell me how to flush a System.err buffer? The problem is when I try to print something using out and err. In that case the order of output is incorrect because it's two different streams.

Thus, the solution I clearly see is to flush my err buffer right after `System.err.print("...")`

Comment: Why do you want to synchronize out and err? It's two different streams for a reason.

Comment: Yes, but I must print errors by err and other information by out

Comment: Well... stdout and stderr are `PrintStream` objects, so they provide a method `flush`... however, I just tested calling these methods and the process does not seem to block until flushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both PrintStreams, so you can call the flush() method.